# VBA Cell search giving me run time 13

Tags: vba, excel

I face a problem in relation to searching for cell values.
I want to search for the value "United Kingdom" in the active worksheet's range and return a given value from with a VLOOKUP-function.

```
Sub UpdateGDP()

Dim rng As Range, cell_search As Range, del As Range, GDP As Range

Set GDP = Worksheets("GDP").Range("A5:C250")
Set rng = Intersect(Range("B:B"), Activesheet.UsedRange)

For Each cell_search In rng
    If (cell_search.Value) = "United Kingdom" Then
        If del Is Nothing Then
            Set del = cell_search
        Else: Set del = Union(del, cell_search)
        End If
    End If
Next cell_search

On Error Resume Next
del.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(United Kingdom,GDP,4,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

It gives me the following error and I simply cannot get it to work:

> Run-time Error 13 - Type Mismatch

```
Sub UpdateGDP()



    Dim rng As Range, cell_search As Range, del As Range, GDP As Range
    Set GDP = Worksheets("GDP").Range("A5:C250", rng.Addres(external:=True))
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheeet.UsedRange)


    For Each cell_search In rng.Cells
        If (cell_search.Value) = "United Kingdom" Then
            If del Is Nothing Then
                Set del = cell_search
            Else: Set del = Union(del, cell_search)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell_search
    del.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""United Kingdom"",GDP,4,FALSE)"
    End Sub
```

> Run-time error 91

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Next cell_search

Comment: Try `del.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""United Kingdom"",GDP,4,FALSE)"`

Comment: Try using `rng.Cells` in your `For Each` instead of just `rng`. Also @Jeeped, wouldn't the reference to `GDP` in the formula need to be changed to cell references as `GDP` is a VBA range object?

Comment: I used your formula but it gave the same run-time error.

Comment: But moving  Next cell_search below On Error Resume Next fixed it though

Comment: That's not fixing the error, that's just resuming the code when the code fails. You shouldn't use `On Error Resume Next` unless you know exactly which error is going to be produced and you know you want to resume after it. If you keep this in the `For Each` loop it is likely your loop isn't finishing.

Comment: @Jordan - yes, it should be the address with external:=true to supply the worksheet.

Comment: Tried fixing it, run-time error 91

Comment: Add `Worksheets("GDP").Range("A5:C250").NAME = "GDP"` before the vlookup

Comment: `ActiveSheeet.UsedRange` should be `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`. Start using `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the `del` range, just apply the formula directly:

```
Sub UpdateGDP()
    Dim rng As Range, cell_search As Range, GDP As Range

    Set GDP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GDP").Range("A5:C250")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'relevant sheet name
        Set rng = Intersect(.Range("B:B"), .UsedRange)
    End With

    For Each cell_search In rng
        If cell_search.Value = "United Kingdom" Then
            cell_search.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""United Kingdom"",GDP!" & GDP.Address & ",3,0)"
        End If
    Next cell_search
End Sub
```

Note:

1. Your VLOOKUP wasn't applied correctly, it also had `col_index_num` parameter value `4` when you only have three columns in your `table array`. I changed this to `3` - you will need to check!
2. It's best to avoid `On Error Resume Next`. You need to find the error and deal with it, not hide it.
3. Where you originally `Set rng` you weren't defining your range fully. This can throw errors.

Comment: I've updated this answer, does it work for you? I've tested it and it's working for me

Answer (score 1):

Start using Option Explicit; you have a typo in `ActiveSheeet.UsedRange`.

You cannot use GDP like this when constructing a string representing a formula unless GDP is a named range with workbook scope. I've added that code for you.

You should make sure that del is at least one cell before writing the formula.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateGDP()
    Dim rng As Range, cell_search As Range, del As Range, GDP As Range

    Set GDP = Worksheets("GDP").Range("A5:C250")
    Worksheets("GDP").Range("A5:C250").Name = "GDP"
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)


    For Each cell_search In rng.Cells
        If (cell_search.Value) = "United Kingdom" Then
            If del Is Nothing Then
                Set del = cell_search
            Else
                 Set del = Union(del, cell_search)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell_search

    If Not del Is Nothing Then _
        del.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""United Kingdom"", GDP, 3, FALSE)"
End Sub
```

Comment: The `VLOOKUP` will still fail, as per my answer - OP needs to clarify this

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed asking for the 4th column within A:C.